# iptables hangs at applying rules

Tags: centos, iptables

I have a set of rules that are supposed to give me the most protection before things like fail2ban and other things are added to the mix.  The issue is that although everything checks out in the test, when I `service iptables restart`  it will shut down just right, but when it goes to apply the rule it hangs.  Here is the set

```
# Allow all traffic.
#---------------------------------------------------------
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [81:5076]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [44:3868]

#---------------------------------------------------------
# protection based on http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/iptables-how-to-use-the-limits-module/
# and https://gist.github.com/virtualstaticvoid/1024546
# and http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-limit-linux-syn-attacks.html
#---------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------
# General rules
#---------------------------------------------------------
# it is gerenally view as best practice to drop all and add
# just what is needed.  Drop and reject to prevent abuse 
# of the system and sour the milk
#---------------------------------------------------------
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP


# Allow incoming HTTP
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming HTTPS
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT



# Allow loopback access
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow packets from internal network to reach external network.
# if eth1 is connected to external network (internet)
# if eth0 is connected to internal network (192.168.1.x)
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

# Allow outbound DNS
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

#---------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE Connections
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Allow MySQL connection only from a specific network
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.200.0/24 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT



#---------------------------------------------------------
# SSH
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Allow ALL incoming SSH
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing SSH
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# limit ssh to 10 connections in 10mins
    # note 198.255.255.255 is fake for this post
#---------------------------------------------------------
-I INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 198.255.255.255 --sport 513:65535 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m recent --set -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 11 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 198.255.255.255 -d 0/0 --sport 22 --dport 513:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


#---------------------------------------------------------
# DoS
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Prevent general DoS attack
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m limit --limit 5/minute --limit-burst 10 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 5/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m limit --limit 5/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

# Syn-flood protection
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT

# Interface 0 incoming syn-flood protection
#---------------------------------------------------------
-N syn_flood
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j syn_flood
-A syn_flood -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 3 -j RETURN
-A syn_flood -j DROP

# Furtive port scanner
#---------------------------------------------------------
#-A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST \
#-A port-scan -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j RETURN
#-A port-scan -j DROP


# Ping of death
#---------------------------------------------------------
#-A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit \ --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT

# Limiting the incoming icmp ping request
#---------------------------------------------------------
-A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit  1/s --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-prefix PING-DROP:
-A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT


#---------------------------------------------------------
# Logging
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Log dropped packets
#---------------------------------------------------------
-N LOGGING
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
-A LOGGING -j DROP



COMMIT
# End
```

I had to remove the `port-scan` and the ping of death rules as it was cause it not to pass the test.  I want to correct that too.

Any ideas why it would pass the test but hang for ever on applying the rules?

**UPDATE**

So far commenting everything except

```
# Allow all traffic.
#---------------------------------------------------------
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [81:5076]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [44:3868]
```

I still was getting odd results like `iptables` hanging while starting back up, to not being able to `yum install *`.  At this point it's like I just need to start over on fixing the rules!

Comment: You're using a lot of modules, have you tried commenting them all out and uncommenting them one by one until you find the problematic rule? Not an answer but it might give you scope on the problem.

Comment: I did.. I was not able to narrow it down just yet, but doesn't mean I am done with that too.  was hoping that someone smarter would be able to spot what would be causing the issue, and why the rule sets to protect are not working.

Comment: @JoelDavis I have commented out many combinations here but have not found out what the real issue is other then my understanding of the issue.